# Форматирование вывода в консоль С#

Tags: консоль, вывод, форматирование

В консоль выводится карта, если в ячейке один объект, выводится его символ, если несколько, то количество объектов в ячейке. Проблема в том, что если объектов 10 и больше, то есть число двузначное, то карта съезжает.

Как избежать подобной ситуации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переопределенный метод для вывода карты:

```csharp
public override string ToString()
{
    var mapStatus = new StringBuilder(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("-", Width*4)) + "-\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
    {
        var strLineCells = new StringBuilder("|");
        for (var j = 0; j < Height; j++)
        {
            var type = new StringBuilder(Cells[i, j].CellType == CellType.Ground ? "-" : "~");

            var objects = new StringBuilder();
            if (Cells[i, j].Objects.Count == 1)
            {
                objects.Append(Cells[i, j].Objects[0].Symbol.ToString());
            }
            else if (Cells[i, j].Objects.Count == 0)
            {
                objects.Append(" ");
            }
            else
            {
                objects.Append(Cells[i, j].Objects.Count.ToString());
            }
            StringBuilder strCell = new StringBuilder($"{type} {objects}|");
            strLineCells.Append(strCell);
        }

        mapStatus.Append(strLineCells + "\n");
    }
            
    return mapStatus.Append(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("-", Width * 4)) + "-\n").ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получше погуглив нашёл ответ

```
StringBuilder strCell = new StringBuilder($"{type} {objects,3}|");
```

С этим справляется число в:

```
{objects,3}
```